# Using entityQuery on node templates

Tags: 8

I've been working with entityQuery in preprocess_node hook in theme file. On a view page I can run the below query and it will return the latest 3 created articles(nodes) from a specific content type. On each specific article(node template) page I would like to use a similar query that will return the latest 3 articles within each. Is there a difference between using this on pages (page.html.twig) as opposed to (node.html.twig)? I basically created a variable to add to the template that returns 3 nodes.

```
  $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
    ->condition('status', 1)
    ->condition('type', 'article')
    ->pager(3)
    ->range(0, 2)
    ->sort('created', 'DESC');

  $nids = $query->execute();
  $nids = $nids;
  $view_mode = 'teaser';

  if (!empty($nids)) {
    $nodes = Node::loadMultiple($nids);
    $view_builder = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder(reset($nodes)->getEntityTypeId());
    $nodes_views = $view_builder->viewMultiple($nodes, 'teaser');
  }
  $variables['article'] = $nodes_views;
```

Comment: PHP code will never work in a Twig template file.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Using a custom query on a view template when querying nodes is what views is for? Query run on templates? What exactly are you trying to achieve? Please update your question and provide more context. Many thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated the question to hopefully be a little more clear.

Comment: Again, what's with Views? Why don't you use Views for that? Have a Views block, get your nodes, choose a display mode for these nodes displaying only the fields you need, and then place the block from the admin UI in whatever region you need it and limit visibility to the exact pages you need it, no?

Comment: Can it be done conditionally based on field selection? User case is content person selects "display latest posts" which could list them from a view, but they can also choose to add them manually which would use different fields.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 8 ships with a view called **Recent content** that displays the most recent Node content on your site. You can edit or clone this view for your purposes. I recommend cloning the view.

I think you would also benefit from a tutorial on using contextual filters. Here's one to get you started: https://redcrackle.com/blog/adding-contextual-filter-view-drupal-8